# Change default expansion panel arrow colour for angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I have an angular expansion panel as shown below. How can i change the color of the arrow below to white?

My code (HTML):

```
<md-expansion-panel>
  <md-expansion-panel-header>
    <md-panel-title>
      Personal data
    </md-panel-title>
    <md-panel-description>
      Type your name and age
    </md-panel-description>
  </md-expansion-panel-header>

  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput placeholder="First name">
  </md-form-field>

  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Age">
  </md-form-field>
</md-expansion-panel>
```

My code (TS):

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic expansion panel
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-overview-example.html',
})
export class ExpansionOverviewExample {}
```

[image]

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Working code is below:

```xml
<md-expansion-panel>
  <md-expansion-panel-header class="specific-class">
    <md-panel-title>
      Personal data
    </md-panel-title>
    <md-panel-description>
      Type your name and age
    </md-panel-description>
  </md-expansion-panel-header>

  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput placeholder="First name">
  </md-form-field>

  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Age">
  </md-form-field>
</md-expansion-panel>
```

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';

/**
 * @title Basic expansion panel
 */
@Component({
  selector: 'expansion-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'expansion-overview-example.html',
  styles: [`
    ::ng-deep .specific-class > .mat-expansion-indicator:after {
      color: white;
    }
  `],
})
export class ExpansionOverviewExample {}
```

Explanation:

1. In order to style nested elements dynamically added by Angular
   Material component you need to use special selector [::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep). 
   That allows to work around [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#view-encapsulation).
2. In order to override built-in component styles applied dynamically
   you need to increase [CSS specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for your selector. That's
   the reason for adding additional CSS class *specific-class*. If you 
   gonna use selector *::ng-deep .mat-expansion-indicator:after* 
   expansion component will override it.

Comment: It looks like [::ng-deep](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#special-selectors) is deprecated. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You can add styles not on the component level:
- provide specific selector for target component
- add custom CSS file with styles
- add link to this file to your page (after CSS with material theme).
But this approach is bug-prone from my POV.

Comment: Update for Angular 9: Use `border-color: white;` instead of `color: white;`

Comment: I believe ">" was just an indicator.

Answer (score 6):

You do not have to use ng-deep. Instead you can add this code to your style sheet:

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header-description, 
.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
    color: white;
}
```

See GitHub-Documentation https://github.com/angular/components/tree/master/src/material/expansion

Comment: This is an important point as `::ng-deep` is deprecated.

Answer (score 5):

**its works for me in this way**

**Html**

```
<mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel class="specific-class"> 
          <mat-expansion-panel-header>
            <a mat-button>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</a>
          </mat-expansion-panel-header>
          <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, placeat.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, placeat.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, placeat.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, placeat.</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Nobis, placeat.</li>
          </ul>
        </mat-expansion-panel>
      </mat-accordion>
```

**Css**

```
/deep/ .mat-expansion-indicator::after, .mat-expansion-panel-header-description { color: red;}
```

Comment: Thanks for the /deep/. I didn't know that and it allowed me to change the color of .mat-expansion-indicator::after

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add it to your global styles.css file. Works for me atleast in version 7.2.

```
.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me in conjunction with adding `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` to the component.

Answer (score 2):

#### for "@angular/material": "^10.2.7"

You add `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` property into your `@Component` decorator

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None // <----
})
```

then

```
.mat-expansion-panel-body {
  padding: 0 !important;
}
```

Then this CSS will work fine with !important or without

`::ng-deep` and `/deep/` will not work on the new version of **angular/material**

Comment: This can have bad side effects when using material

Answer (score 2):

This works for me

```
::ng-deep .mat-expansion-indicator, .mat-expansion-indicator:after {
 color: green;}
```

Comment: Does not work in Angular 14

Answer (score 1):

this works on me **2018**

#### html file

```
<md-expansion-panel>
  <md-expansion-panel-header class="specific-class">
    <md-panel-title>
      Personal data
    </md-panel-title>
    <md-panel-description>
      Type your name and age
    </md-panel-description>
  </md-expansion-panel-header>

  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput placeholder="First name">
  </md-form-field>

  <md-form-field>
    <input mdInput placeholder="Age">
  </md-form-field>
</md-expansion-panel>
```

#### styles.css

```
.specific-class > .mat-expansion-indicator, .mat-expansion-indicator:after {
  color: red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can directly go to material.scss in your app if you have installed angular material using npm and change the color of the arrow with class .mat-expansion-indicator:after.

Comment: Thanks! Worked fine for me but only with !important added.

Answer (score 0):

For me this is what worked:

```
.mat-expansion-indicator::after{
    border-color: red;
}
```