# How to move Mat expansion indication?

Tags: angular, material-design

Is it possible to move the mat expansion indicator (Angular, Material Design) to set it before the title ?

No informations about that on material documentation https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview

[image]

Thank you :)

Comment: there is no default option for that. but you can disable the default arrow and create your own on the left side of the panel.
here is the API Doc: https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/api

Comment: I agree with @ShadowFoOrm, override the styles. But I think it's a bad idea from a usability viewpoint: Google created material design to make applications look and behave the same. The user expects this icon to be on the right.

Answer (score 11):

you can always override default style.

```
.mat-expansion-panel-header {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;

  .mat-content {
    padding-left: 12px;
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried your css. The arrow is on the left but stuck to the title (.mat-content code is not applyed and I don't know why).

Comment: A genius solution, I just had to play with the transform:rotate a little to get the behavior I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: works. However, I had to do the following for padding and style. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46540080/change-default-expansion-panel-arrow-colour-for-angular-material

Comment: @Java_deep, so is this the correct answer? If yes, maybe you can mark it?

Comment: This Worked well but how do you change the indicator to rotate to the right now since its on the left side

Comment: @Flash if you inspect the right column you can see that it adds a `transform: rotate(180deg);` all you need to do is to override / change it as you want ex: `-180deg`; basically just reverse engineer;

Comment: thanks for your reply I ended up asking my question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852932/changing-rotation-of-mat-expansion-indicator
It looks like it's not possible to do it the way I want it after trying: `  transform: rotate(225deg) !important;  ` if your able to do it without having a custom directive let me know please: https://stackblitz.com/edit/indicatorrotation?file=styles.css

Answer (score 4):

You can easily do this with the following code!

```
<mat-accordion>
        <mat-expansion-panel [togglePosition]="'before'">
          <mat-expansion-panel-header >
            <mat-panel-title>

            </mat-panel-title>

          </mat-expansion-panel-header>

        </mat-expansion-panel>
</mat-accordion>
```

Just add **[togglePosition]=" 'before' "**

Comment: I'm pretty sure it didn't exist when I post this but it could be useful from now :)

Comment: For angular material 8.0.0^ users this is the preferrable solution. Works perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

with Angular 14, you can try this:

```css
.mat-expansion-panel-header {
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}

.mat-expansion-panel-header-title {
  padding-left: 12px;
}
```