# Changing Rotation of Mat Expansion Indicator

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, transform

I was successfully able to move the  mat Indicator to the left, instead of the right and I used the transform attribute to make it turn inward when expanding. However I want the indicator to face upward when expanded and downward when collapsed. How do I properly style it to achieve this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/indicatorrotation?file=styles.css

**expansion-overview-example.css**

```
  .mat-expansion-panel-header {
       flex-direction: row-reverse;
   }
```

**Global styles.css**

```
  .mat-expansion-indicator::after {
      transform: rotate(225deg) !important;  
}
```

Comment: Hi! again. make the **globalstyle.css** as `.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
      transform: rotate(45deg) !important;  
}`

Comment: hey thanks for helping. I tried that but that makes the arrow move away from the content (bottom to left instead) of towards it(from bottom to right)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

mat expansion indicator's rotation is handled by [this animation](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/d29df3813eb340a6a30e155bf90ddb1d2befe4e0/src/material/expansion/expansion-animations.ts#L51). as it can be seen there it is straightforward `rotate(180deg)` (180deg clockwise). and indicator initially has `rotate(45deg)` which show downward icon by default when panel is closed and upward icon when panel is open with clockwise animation.

when you apply rotation with;

```
.mat-expansion-indicator::after {
    transform: rotate(225deg) !important;  
}
```

icon is rotated upwards initially when panel is closed, when clicked it is rotated by 180deg clockwise. at this point you cannot show downwards icon when closed and upwards when open because of `rotate(225deg)` if you change that you loose inward turning because animation starts clockwise, but we need exactly the opposite.

eventually it is not possible to have counter-clockwise rotation without overriding default animation. Unfortunately, Angular Material doesn't have any mechanism to override default animations, [as seen here](https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8857) .

so my solution is to completely disable default animations on `mat-expansion-panel-header` and implement a custom directive that imitates [this animation](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/d29df3813eb340a6a30e155bf90ddb1d2befe4e0/src/material/expansion/expansion-animations.ts#L51) but counter-clockwise.

first disable default animation on `mat-expansion-panel-header`;

`<mat-expansion-panel-header [@.disabled]="true">`

then create new animations in `styles.css` with [same timing and behavior](https://github.com/angular/components/blob/d29df3813eb340a6a30e155bf90ddb1d2befe4e0/src/material/expansion/expansion-animations.ts#L21) as default animation.

```css
@keyframes inwards-open {
  0%   { transform: rotate(0deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(-135deg); }
}

@keyframes inwards-close {
  0%   { transform: rotate(-135deg); }
  100% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
}

.openAnimate {
  animation: inwards-open 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4,0.0,0.2,1) !important;
}

.closeAnimate {
  animation: inwards-close 225ms cubic-bezier(0.4,0.0,0.2,1) !important;
}
```

and implement a custom directive that handles animation status based on panel open/close events

```js
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { fromEvent, Subscription } from 'rxjs';

@Directive({
  selector: '[appCustomMatExpansionToggle]'
})
export class CustomMatExpansionToggleDirective implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  private elem: HTMLSpanElement;
  private uns: Subscription;
  constructor(private elRef: ElementRef) {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.elem = this.elRef.nativeElement.querySelector(".mat-expansion-indicator");

    this.uns = fromEvent(this.elem, 'animationend').subscribe(() => {
      this.elem.classList.remove("openAnimate");
      this.elem.classList.remove("closeAnimate");
    });
  }

  @HostListener("opened")
  onOpen() {
    this.elem.classList.add("openAnimate");
  }

  @HostListener("closed")
  onClose() {
    this.elem.classList.add("closeAnimate");
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    this.uns.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

and finally apply the custom directive to `mat-expansion-panel`

```html
<mat-expansion-panel appCustomMatExpansionToggle>
```

here is a working demo https://stackblitz.com/edit/indicatorrotation-mp73uh

Comment: Thanks since it's impossible I don't know if it's worth me creating a whole custom directive but I will see.

Comment: actually i was thinking the same when i was trying the above solution. this one is the only solution i could think of. i also thought about some css solutions but in the end animations must be overriden. so i hope this somehow helps. have a nice day.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate you taking out the time to do that!

Answer (score 6):

Disable default animation:

```
<mat-expansion-panel-header [@.disabled]="true">
```

Rewrite styles in some global styles.scss

```
  .mat-expansion-panel {
    .mat-expansion-indicator {
      transition: transform .3s ease;

      &::after {
        transform: rotate(-135deg);
      }
    }

    &.mat-expanded {
      .mat-expansion-indicator {
        transform: rotate(40deg) !important;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks! This should be accepted answer.

Comment: I think the second transform should be 
`transform: rotate(180deg) !important;` if you want to have the arrow appear '^' by default and on expand 'v'

Comment: `[@.disabled]="true"` is briliant. Thanks. Should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Ivan, Actually, you only need this (no need to disable animations) (I know ng-deep is deprecated) :

```
:host ::ng-deep .mat-expansion-panel {
  .mat-expansion-indicator {

    &::after {
      transform: rotate(-135deg) !important;
    }
  }

  &.mat-expanded {
    .mat-expansion-indicator {
      transform: rotate(180deg) !important;
    }
  }
}
```