# how to change Angular mat-expansion-panel direction

Tags: angular, mat-expansion-panel

I'm using angular material component "mat-expansion-panel". the default opening direction for this component is down.
i want the panel to open in different directions (left, right, up)
how can i do that.

Comment: See if this helps:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56852932/changing-rotation-of-mat-expansion-indicator

Answer (score 1):

There are only one way to open `mat-expansion-panel`. Its default nature is open down side as drop down works. But if you want to open it left or right side then you can use side bar.

https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples

Answer (score 0):

Just do something like that

```
    <p>Main text</p>
    @if (showFiller) {
      <p>Extra Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur.</p>
    }
    <button (click)="showFiller = !showFiller" mat-raised-button>
      Toggle extra text
    </button>
```